# how can enable dotnet https for developing in localhost

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

**i'm new in dotnet and i created webapi**:
1- dotnet new sln 
2- dotnet new webapi -o ApiConfig
3- dotnet dev-certs https -t

but when i use (dotnet watch run) it show me: 
*(Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.  ($XAUTHORITY is /tmp/xauth-1000-_0 which is owned by username.)
[94132:94132:0307/201513.896940:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.)*
i checked this web site but taht not working

[image]

Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page says your connection is not properly secured which is obvious because you are using self-signed SSL certificate. You can press the button 'Advanced' and you'll see a link with text "Proceed to [website address] (unsafe)"... just click on this link.

Comment: I mean, like Windows, I can not run the program with https?

Comment: You can, this error is not related to OS. This an info that browser brings to you and it means "remote SSL certificate is not trusted by anyone else, be careful".